Gozero goctl generate code from datasource not getting sql data type nullstring golang
I generate code from datasource and don't get nullstring sql data type, but generating from sql file still get nullstring data type.
its work (from sql file):
    goctl model mysql ddl --src schema/db.sql --dir ./internal/model --style go_zero 

its not work (from datasource):
    goctl model mysql datasource --url "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/qrmenu" --dir ./internal/model --style go_zero --table "*" --cache=true 

the result i expected:
GroupToppingOption struct {
        Id             string         `db:"id"`
        ShopId         sql.NullString `db:"shop_id"`
        GroupToppingId string         `db:"group_topping_id"`
        Name           sql.NullString `db:"name"`
        Price          sql.NullInt64  `db:"price"`
        CreateAt       time.Time      `db:"create_at"`
        UpdateAt       time.Time      `db:"update_at"`
        CreateBy       string         `db:"create_by"`
        UpdateBy       string         `db:"update_by"`
    }

